# Twig loop variables with Doctrine 2 Paginator, is this a bug?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm using [Doctrine 2 Paginator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) and i'm experiencing a bug (maybe) with Twig. Consider a simple [`Paginator`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Pagination/Paginator.php) initialization:

```
    $current = 1;
    $limit   = 5;
    $offset  = ($current - 1) * $limit;

    $qb->setFirstResult($offset)->setMaxResults($this->limit);

    // No fetch joins
    $items = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($qb->getQuery, false);

    // Total count
    var_dump($items->count()); // Prints 8

    // Number of items displayed
    var_dump(count($items)); // Prints 5

    // Items
    foreach($items as $item) :
        var_dump($items->getId()); // Prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    endif;
```

Counts are just fine to me. But after assigning it to Twig with `array('items' => $items)`:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ loop.index }}/{{ loop.length }}
{% endfo %}
```

Output is wrong, in particular `loop.length` refers to the entire collection (not the current set of items). So, for example, you can't use `loop.last`:

```
1/8
2/8
3/8
4/8
5/8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self answer. This code from Doctrine documentation has led me astray:

```
$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);

$c = count($paginator);
foreach ($paginator as $post) {
    echo $post->getHeadline() . "\n";
}
```

Wrong. You have to assign the iterator to Twig, not the paginator instance itself:

```
return array('items' => $paginator->getIterator());
```

**EDIT**: sorry i found that `count($paginator) == $paginator->count()`, so current items count is `$paginator->getIterator()->count()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend what @gremo says, for a simple pager (if you aren't proud!) you can do something like this in the controller:

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
// Select your items.
$dql = "SELECT i FROM ShopBundle:Issue i ORDER BY i.liveDate DESC";
// Limit per page.
$limit = 10;
// See what page we're on from the query string.
$page = $this->getRequest()->query->get("page", 1);
// Determine our offset.
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
// Create the query
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$query->setFirstResult($offset)->setMaxResults($limit);
// Create a pager object.
$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = FALSE);
...
return $this->render('ShopBundle:Issue:list.html.twig', array(
    'totalPages' => (int) ($paginator->count() / $limit), // Calc total number of pages.
    'currentPage' => $page,
    'issues' => $paginator->getIterator(),
    )
);
```

Then in the template (as an twig include):

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(route) }}">&laquo;</a>
        </li>
        {% if currentPage != 1 %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(route, {'page': (currentPage - 1)}) }}">&lsaquo;</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in 1..totalPages %}
        <li>
            <a{% if  i == currentPage %} class="disabled"{% endif %} href="{{ path(route, {'page': i}) }}">{{ i }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if currentPage != totalPages %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(route, {'page': (currentPage + 1)}) }}">&rsaquo;</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}

        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(route, {'page': totalPages}) }}">&raquo;</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Where `route` is the `'route_to_your_controller'`.

Answer (score 0):

The page to Doctrine2 Paginator does provide much. I also could not find

Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

Did you download additional files? I would really like to use your answer rather than some of the bundles that are available.